# Change data pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, format

I want to change the date format in a pandas dataframe. I foud out that it should be something like the code below:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

The problem is that I get a "SettingWithCopyWarning" everytime I do this. Does somebody know a proper way to do this?

Comment: It's `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d-%m-%Y")`. But the `SettingWithCopyWarning` is coming from earlier in your code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Comment: I'm not sure if the error is coming from earlier code. When I delete the formatting line, the warning disapears.

Comment: Full text of the warning is:c:\users\mbru\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:28: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy